# swift Crash log

Tags: swift, logging, crash

I used Fabric to monitor the crash in my app, but after locating my method in the printed log, I did not find a problem with the test. Please help me to see what is the reason? Thank you~~~
Log like this:

```
# 0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  EFB                            0x1041e2018 specialized FightPlanViewController.dispatchClick(\_:) (FightPlanViewController.swift:346)
1  EFB                            0x1041db4d8 @objc FightPlanViewController.dispatchClick(\_:) + 4371969240
2  UIKit                          0x18b5c26c8 -\[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
3  UIKit                          0x18b6e38a4 -\[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
4  UIKit                          0x18b5c877c -\[UIControl \_sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
5  UIKit                          0x18b6fe1dc -\[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 572
6  UIKit                          0x18bba3dd8 \_UIGestureEnvironmentSortAndSendDelayedTouches + 4340
7  UIKit                          0x18bba0b50 \_UIGestureEnvironmentUpdate + 1236
8  UIKit                          0x18b63b540 -\[UIGestureEnvironment \_deliverEvent:toGestureRecognizers:usingBlock:] + 404
9  UIKit                          0x18b63b078 -\[UIGestureEnvironment \_updateGesturesForEvent:window:] + 276
10 UIKit                          0x18b63a8dc -\[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3132
11 UIKit                          0x18b639238 -\[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
12 UIKit                          0x18be1ac0c \_\_dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2340
13 UIKit                          0x18be1d1b8 \_\_handleEventQueueInternal + 4744
14 UIKit                          0x18be16258 \_\_handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
15 CoreFoundation                 0x18183b404 __CFRUNLOOP\_IS\_CALLING\_OUT\_TO\_A\_SOURCE0\_PERFORM\_FUNCTION__ + 24
16 CoreFoundation                 0x18183ac2c \_\_CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 276
17 CoreFoundation                 0x18183879c \_\_CFRunLoopRun + 1204
18 CoreFoundation                 0x181758da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
19 GraphicsServices               0x18373b020 GSEventRunModal + 100
20 UIKit                          0x18b73978c UIApplicationMain + 236
21 EFB                            0x1041470c8 main (AppDelegate.swift:18)
22 libdyld.dylib                  0x1811e9fc0 start + 4

--

            0x1811e9fc0 start + 4

# 1. Thread
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x181319d84 \_\_workq\_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7eb4 \_pthread\_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b08 start\_wqthread + 4

# 2. Thread
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x1813190f4 \_\_psynch\_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814bbc90 \_pthread\_cond\_wait$VARIANT$mp + 644
2  PSPDFKit                       0x104cd30b8 PSPDFBundleImage + 208312
3  PSPDFKit                       0x104cd151c PSPDFBundleImage + 201244
4  PSPDFKit                       0x104f13328 boost::thread::start\_thread\_noexcept() + 392
5  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9220 \_pthread\_body + 272
6  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9110 \_pthread\_body + 290
7  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b10 thread\_start + 4

# 3. com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x1812f7e08 mach\_msg\_trap + 8
1  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x1812f7c80 mach\_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18183ae40 \_\_CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181838908 \_\_CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181758da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x1821cd674 -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x1821cd51c -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 148
7  UIKit                          0x18b41e7e4 -\[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8  Foundation                     0x1822ddefc __NSThread\_\_start__ + 1040
9  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9220 \_pthread\_body + 272
10 libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9110 \_pthread\_body + 290
11 libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b10 thread\_start + 4

# 4. com.twitter.crashlytics.ios.MachExceptionServer
0  EFB                            0x1042b861c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4372874780
1  EFB                            0x1042b861c CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4372874780
2  EFB                            0x1042b84d8 CLSProcessRecordAllThreads + 4372874456
3  EFB                            0x1042a79b8 CLSHandler + 4372806072
4  EFB                            0x1042a29cc CLSMachExceptionServer + 4372785612
5  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9220 \_pthread\_body + 272
6  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9110 \_pthread\_body + 290
7  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b10 thread\_start + 4

# 5. CCP Socket Thead
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x1812f7e08 mach\_msg\_trap + 8
1  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x1812f7c80 mach\_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18183ae40 \_\_CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181838908 \_\_CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181758da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  Foundation                     0x1821cd674 -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 304
6  Foundation                     0x1822421a8 -\[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7  EFB                            0x1042f0028 -\[MPASConnectTask networkRequestThreadEntryPoint:] (MPASConnectTask.m:173)
8  Foundation                     0x1822ddefc __NSThread\_\_start__ + 1040
9  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9220 \_pthread\_body + 272
10 libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9110 \_pthread\_body + 290
11 libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b10 thread\_start + 4

# 6. com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x1812f7e08 mach\_msg\_trap + 8
1  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x1812f7c80 mach\_msg + 72
2  CoreFoundation                 0x18183ae40 \_\_CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 196
3  CoreFoundation                 0x181838908 \_\_CFRunLoopRun + 1568
4  CoreFoundation                 0x181758da8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 552
5  CFNetwork                      0x1820664b0 -\[\_\_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 220
6  Foundation                     0x1822ddefc __NSThread\_\_start__ + 1040
7  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9220 \_pthread\_body + 272
8  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9110 \_pthread\_body + 290
9  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b10 thread\_start + 4

# 7. com.apple.CFSocket.private
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x181319538 \_\_select + 8
1  CoreFoundation                 0x181843378 \_\_CFSocketManager + 644
2  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9220 \_pthread\_body + 272
3  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b9110 \_pthread\_body + 290
4  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b10 thread\_start + 4

# 8. com.apple.root.default-qos
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x1813190f4 \_\_psynch\_cvwait + 8
1  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814bbc90 \_pthread\_cond\_wait$VARIANT$mp + 644
2  EFB                            0x1042f1690 -\[MPASConnectTask onCall] (MPASConnectTask.m:455)
3  EFB                            0x1042f2480 -\[MPRequestRetrier doTaskRun] (MPRequestRetrier.m:86)
4  libdispatch.dylib              0x181184b24 \_dispatch\_call\_block\_and\_release + 24
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x181184ae4 \_dispatch\_client\_callout + 16
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x18118bc08 \_dispatch\_queue\_override\_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 716
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x181191d30 \_dispatch\_root\_queue\_drain + 588
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x181191a80 \_dispatch\_worker\_thread3 + 120
9  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7fac \_pthread\_wqthread + 1176
10 libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b08 start\_wqthread + 4

# 9. Thread
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x181319d84 \_\_workq\_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7eb4 \_pthread\_wqthread + 928
2  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b08 start\_wqthread + 4

# 10. Thread
0  libsystem\_kernel.dylib         0x181319d84 \_\_workq\_kernreturn + 8
1  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b80a0 \_pthread\_wqthread + 1420
2  libsystem\_pthread.dylib        0x1814b7b08 start\_wqthread + 4


@objc func dispatchClick(_ sender:UIButton){
    let tag = sender.tag-100
    sender.isEnabled = false
    let flightId:String = FightModelManger.defaultManger.selectAll()[tag].flightId
    if sender.titleLabel?.text == "下载"||sender.titleLabel?.text == "DOWNLOAD"||sender.titleLabel?.text == "未生成"||sender.titleLabel?.text == "UNREALEASED"{
        self.checkDispatchUpdate(flightId: flightId, tag, true)
    }else{ 
        self.checkDispatchUpdate(flightId: flightId,tag, false)
    }
}



func checkDispatchUpdate(flightId:String,_ index:Int,_ isFirst:Bool){
    let button = self.view.viewWithTag(100+index) as! UIButton    
    let model = DispatchInfoModelManger.defaultManger.selectflightId(flightId: flightId)
    var  para = ["flightId":"","lastUpdateTime":""]
    if model.count == 0{
        para["flightId"] = flightId
        para["lastUpdateTime"] = "1900-01-01 00:00:00"
    }else{
        if let time = model.first?.dispatchTime{
            para["flightId"] = flightId
            para["lastUpdateTime"] = time
        }
    }
    let manger = Alamofire.SessionManager.default  //  网络超时
    manger.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 10
    if NetWorkState.isReachable(){
        manger.request(ReleaseInfoCheckURL, method: .get, parameters: para, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
            switch response.result{
            case .success:
                if let dic = response.result.value {
                    let status = (dic as! NSDictionary)["status"]as! String
                    if status == "0"{  // 表示放行资料可以下载
                        self.downloadDispatchInfo(flightId: flightId, index)
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                             if self.aUser.nation == "CN"{
                                SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "正在下载放行资料,请稍候")
                                button.isEnabled = true
                            }else if self.aUser.nation == "EN"{
                                SVProgressHUD.show(withStatus: "Downloading the Release Data, please Wait a Minute")
                                button.isEnabled = true
                            }
                            SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(kRGBColorFromHex(rgbValue:0x66CDAA))
                            SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor.black)
                            Mainwindow?.addSubview(self.maskView)
                        }
                    }else {
                        if model.count == 0{ 
                            if self.aUser.nation == "CN"{
                                self.alter(title: "抱歉", "放行资料未生成")
                                button.isEnabled = true
                            }else if self.aUser.nation == "EN"{
                                self.alter(title: "SORRY", "Release Data Not Generated")
                                button.isEnabled = true
                            }
                        }else{ 
                            let release = ReleaseViewController()
                            release.flightId = flightId
                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(release, animated: true)
                            button.isEnabled = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                if (error._code == -1005)||(error._code == -1009){
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                    self.maskView.removeFromSuperview()
                    if self.aUser.nation == "CN"{
                        SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "网络超时或链接错误")
                        button.isEnabled = true
                    }else if self.aUser.nation == "EN"{
                        SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: "Network Timeout or Link Error")
                        button.isEnabled = true
                    }
                    SVProgressHUD.dismiss(withDelay: 2)
                    return
                }
            }
        })
    }else{ 
        if model.count == 0{ 
            if self.aUser.nation == "CN"{
                 self.alter(title: "无网络", "抱歉无法检测")
                button.isEnabled = true
            }else if self.aUser.nation == "EN"{
                 self.alter(title: "No Network", "Sorry! Unable to Check")
                button.isEnabled = true
            }
        }else{
            let release = ReleaseViewController()
            release.flightId = flightId
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(release, animated: true)
            button.isEnabled = true
        }
    }
}
```

in this log i find the FightPlanViewController.dispatchClick(_:),i guess it may crashed in this ,but i use ipad to test it ,but i can not find the reason . can u help me ? thanks a lot

Comment: Whats the crash message? Usually gives you a reason like found nil, or array index out of bounds etc etc. We cant spot the issue without seeing the function

Comment: @Scriptable this log is showed in Fabric...  i used my phone to test it but fond no questions......  it makes me depressed

Comment: Unfortunately I dont think we can help you. the question is too broad. We need more information

Comment: It is impossible to help without `dispatchClick` code at least. Or look at line 346 of `FightPlanViewController.swift` yourself.

Comment: @Stimorol i send my code.  hope more more coders can see it

Comment: @leeSin From the code provided I'm guessing that this `let flightId:String = FightModelManger.defaultManger.selectAll()[tag].flightId` is on line 346. Since you don't check if index is inside array bounds, it may easily crash your app.

Comment: The tag value of the button is generated based on the number of database, it should not be wrong, but it does not rule out special circumstances! Thank you for your valuable advice @Stimorol

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the top of the page in Fabric, it will show the file and the line at which the application crashed.
See example:

[image]